# Process stuck with black cmd screen

Tags: c#, process

So I have this code to launch a bat script which will execute certain java commands, starting with "java -version" just to get some output. The first time I call it it works, but the second time I am stuck with a black cmd screen.

The same code is used but in different locations.

```
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
StartInfo.FileName = path + "javaScript.bat";
StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + path + "\"";
StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

proc.StartInfo = StartInfo;

proc.Start();

proc.WaitForExit();

string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Anyone can help me figure out what happens? Since I don't get any echo I doubt the bat file gets stuck anywhere (echo is on and the first command is java -version so it should write something instead of just getting stuck at black cmd window)

Comment: try writing out the [standard error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx)

Comment: I cant since im forever stuck in WaitForExit() since the cmd window just sits there doing nothing.

Comment: See the link I included.. it shows that you should do this *before* wait for exit

Answer (score 3):

```
        proc.WaitForExit();
        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

You are deadlocking the process with this code.  It cannot exit until you empty its output buffer.  But you don't read its output until it exits.  The program can't continue, nor can you.  A "deadly embrace", better known as deadlock.

Simply swap these two lines of code to fix the problem.

Do note that you have a problem with StandardError as well, it will still deadlock when it sends a bunch of error text to that stream.  If you don't want to read it then don't redirect it.  If you want to make it completely solid then you'll need to use BeginErrorReadLine and BeginOutputReadLine.

Comment: swapped them, same problem. I think i found the cause, after i killed java.exe, it started to execute, it seems java was still busy doing something else. Any way to resolve this or is that a complete other question and should be discussed elsewhere?

Comment: Sure, killing the process will solve the deadlock.  You also have a problem with StandardError, I added a paragraph.  If you think java.exe is to blame then try it simply without redirecting at all.